# И еще этимология: слова "нахлобучить"

Tags: этимология

Искала поиском: вроде такого вопроса не было. Интересует слово "нахлобучить". Какое у него происхождение и корень?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы интересовались происхождением.А теперь Вам интересно, как это слово правильно применять. За этим обратимся в толковый словарь.

Большой толковый словарь

НАХЛОБУЧИТЬ, -чу, -чишь; св. что. Разг.
Надеть, надвинуть низко на лоб, на уши и т.п. (головной убор). Н. шляпу, фуражку. Н. шапку на голову. < Нахлобучивать, -аю, -аешь; нсв. Нахлобучиваться, -ается; страд.

Выходит, ошибки нет. Со времени происхождения "нахлобучить" превратилось в слово, характеризующее действие, иногда иронически.

Answer (score 1):

Не могу воспользоваться комментариями, поэтому вынуждена задавать возникшие по ходу чтения вопросы в ответах. Получается, фраза "нахлобучить шапку" содержит грамматическую ошибку?

Comment: Скорее, тавтологию. Получается что-то вроде "прошляпить шляпу"

Answer (score 0):

НАХЛОБУЧИТЬ. Искон. Фонетическое изменение наклобучить, суф.-преф. производного от *клобук* "шапка". Ср. *прошляпить*, *околпачить*.
 Этимологический словарь, 2004